# How to get the second word in a string using t-sql?

Tags: string, t-sql, parsing, split, charindex

I would like to extract the second word from a string or the phrase between the first and third spaces.

for example

'The Boeing Corporation'

I would like 'Boeing'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> declare @sentence nvarchar(264);
>
> set @sentence = 'The Boeing Corporation';
>
> select ltrim(substring(@sentence,charindex(' ',@sentence), CHARINDEX(' ',ltrim(SUBSTRING(@sentence,charindex(' ',@sentence),LEN(@sentence)-charindex(' ',@sentence)))) ))
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | Boeing           |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=42307a9df55b4ba16abc4cdb7b20fb13)*

Answer (score 1):

Just another option using a bit of XML

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('The Boeing Corporation')

Select SomeCol
      ,Pos2 = cast('<x>' + replace(A.SomeCol,' ','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(50)')
 From  @YourTable A
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol                 Pos2
The Boeing Corporation  Boeing
```